# How can I reset the default font (because of blurred characters)?

Tags: fonts, mate-desktop

I've recently installed some fonts and now all system menus are screwed:

[image]

Some single characters (`P`, `b`, `t`, `o`, `w`, `B`, `p` ... that seem to be all characters) are blurred out. I don't know why. How can I fix that?

I currently run "Linux Mint 16 Petra" with MATE (which is based on Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface. ??

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't a complete solution, but a work-around

1. Open `mate-appearance-properties`:

[image]

2. Go to "fonts"
3. Change "application font" from "Sans Regular" to something different. In my case it was [Ubuntu Regular](http://font.ubuntu.com/).